# XLWings Format Painter

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Using XLWings/Python, is it possible to use Excel's Format Painter to copy the format from one cell/range to another?

I have found an example of how to do it using VBA here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/format-painter/

But I can't work out how to convert that into Python code.

Answer (score 2):

xlwings has this built into the `paste` method, see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.paste

So you can do:

```py
import xliwngs as xw

book = xw.Book("...")
book.sheets[0]["A1"].copy()
book.sheets[0]["A2"].paste("formats")
```